# Qt Creator изменения свойства чекбокса созданного без UI

Tags: c++, qt

имеется такая кнопка:

```
void RTIMULibDemoGL::test_connection(){
    int res = internet_test();
        if (res == 1){
            "код изменения чекбокса"
        }
}
```

Которая создана через

```
QPushButton *internetConnection = new QPushButton("Internet");
```

как и чекбокс

```
QCheckBox *internetConnectionCheck = new QCheckBox("");
internetConnectionCheck->setEnabled(false);
```

Как изменить свойства чекбокса?

Comment: впишите internetConnectionCheck->setChekt(true)

Comment: можно более развернутый код?

Comment: @Akuma925 что бы вы хотели увидеть?

Comment: просто вы уже не первый подобный вопрос задете. Там в QtCreator есть асситент который содержит ответы на все ваши вопросы и есть книга М.Шлее по Qt в которой развернуто рассказаны все моменты которые вы спрашиваете. Просто скаладывается ощущение, что мы за вас проект пишем. А про изменение свойств cb нет разници, в том как менять, есть отличие как он создан, т.е. как к нему обратиться.

Comment: @Akuma925 http://pastebin.com/3VACa4Ng http://pastebin.com/htMztMK1

Comment: Поясните какие свойства.